# Getting the minimum or maximum of two similar columns in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, min

I just started learning Scala and I'm trying to figure out a way to get the `min` of two or multiple `Columns` of the same type in a `DataFrame`. I have the following code which gives me the `min` and `max` of a `Column` individually.

```
inputDF.select(min($"dropoff_longitude")).show
inputDF.select(max($"pickup_longitude")).show
```

How do I get the `min` of both the `Columns`, `dropoff_longitude` and  `pickup_longitude`. I did it like this

```
scala.math.min(
   inputDF.select(min($"pickup_longitude")).head.getFloat(0),
   inputDF.select(min($"dropoff_longitude")).head.getFloat(0)
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can do something like this:

```
// assume all columns are of type Int, it could be other numeric type as well
val df = Seq((1,2),(3,4)).toDF("A", "B")    

df.agg(min($"A"), min($"B")).first().toSeq.map{ case x: Int => x }.min
// res14: Int = 1
```

Comment: So what you suggest is to convert the `min`s of all different `Column`s into a  `Seq` and then get the `min` using the `Seq`'s `min` api ?

Comment: That's how I would solve the problem. And it seems natural to me if I can hold all values in a single container.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Psidom

Answer (score 13):

You can use `least` and `greatest` Spark SQL functions in select expressions for this purpose. In your case it will look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val minLongitude =
    df.select(least($"pickup_longitude", $"dropoff_longitude") as "least_longitude")
      .agg(min($"least_longitude"))
      .head.getFloat(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, it might be more efficient to avoid `collect` so that a Spark query plan is actualized once (hence, fewer data reads and, possibly, less shuffling). In this case, you can use e.g.:

```
val minValDf = inputDf.agg(min(col(inputCol1)).as(inputCol1), min(col(inputCol2).as(inputCol2)))
val minDf = minValDf.withColumn("minCol",
    when(col(inputCol1).gt(col(inputCol2)), col(inputCol2))
    .otherwise(col(inputCol1)))
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you expanded on `collect` and why someone would prefer to avoid using it.

Comment: I've expanded the answer